# Aggregate multiple tables with dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I have a list of contacts, and three tables with different information in them containing date-related data about the contacts.

What I would like to do, is show per-month counts from each table:

```
ID Date       Hist Trck Evt
1  2016-01-01    0    0   0
1  2016-02-01    1    0   1
1  2016-03-01    2    0   1
1  2016-04-01    0    5   1
```

I have the results for each type individually by just grouping on the PersonId and Date:

```
SELECT PersonId AS CID, 
       HistoryDate,
       COUNT(id) Records 
FROM @History  
GROUP BY PersonId, 
         HistoryDate
```

And this gets me the totals for the 3 data tables, but not grouped by Person ID:

```
SELECT DateMonth, pvt.[EH], pvt.[ET], pvt.[EV] 
FROM
(
    SELECT Id AS CID,  HistoryDate AS DateMonth, 'EH' AS RecordType, COUNT(id) Records FROM @History   GROUP BY Id,  HistoryDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Id AS CID,  TrackingDate AS DateMonth, 'ET' AS RecordType, COUNT(id) Records FROM @Tracking GROUP BY Id,  TrackingDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Id AS CID, EventDate  AS DateMonth, 'EV' AS RecordType, COUNT(id) Records FROM @Events      GROUP BY Id, EventDate
) as x
PIVOT( COUNT(CID) FOR RecordType IN ( [EH], [ET], [EV] ) ) as pvt

DateMonth               EH          ET          EV
----------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 1           1           1
2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 2           0           1
2016-04-01 00:00:00.000 0           5           1
2016-05-01 00:00:00.000 1           2           0
2016-06-01 00:00:00.000 2           2           0
2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 2           0           0
2016-08-01 00:00:00.000 2           0           0
```

I can't seem to add a second column to the pivot, so it has `Id`, `DateMonth` and then the three pivot fields.

I'm just struggling to combine these into a single recordset with the contact data.

What I am actually getting is a lot of records for each contact and date, instead of one.

I suspect it's something obvious, but the requirements have changed over time (and in reality the tables are complex and enormous) so I have probably just got my mind down a dead-end.

Here's some example schema. (You can also run it [here](http://rextester.com/YNFXLB6938))

```
DECLARE @Contacts TABLE (
    Id int not null,
    Email nvarchar(50)
);

DECLARE @History TABLE (
    Id int not null,
    PersonId int,
    HistoryDate datetime
);

DECLARE @Tracking TABLE (
    Id int not null,
    PersonId int,
    TrackingDate datetime
);

DECLARE @Events TABLE (
    Id int not null,
    PersonId int,
    EventDate datetime
);
```

And here's a bit of sample data for one contact:

```
INSERT INTO @Contacts VALUES (1, 'someone@gmail.com');

INSERT INTO @History VALUES (1, 1, '2016-02-01');
INSERT INTO @History VALUES (2, 1, '2016-03-01');
INSERT INTO @History VALUES (3, 1, '2016-03-01');
INSERT INTO @History VALUES (4, 1, '2016-05-01');
INSERT INTO @History VALUES (5, 1, '2016-06-01');
INSERT INTO @History VALUES (6, 1, '2016-06-01');
INSERT INTO @History VALUES (7, 1, '2016-07-01');
INSERT INTO @History VALUES (8, 1, '2016-07-01');
INSERT INTO @History VALUES (9, 1, '2016-08-01');
INSERT INTO @History VALUES (10,1, '2016-08-01');

INSERT INTO @Tracking VALUES (1,  1, '2016-02-01');
INSERT INTO @Tracking VALUES (2,  1, '2016-04-01');
INSERT INTO @Tracking VALUES (3,  1, '2016-04-01');
INSERT INTO @Tracking VALUES (4,  1, '2016-04-01');
INSERT INTO @Tracking VALUES (5,  1, '2016-04-01');
INSERT INTO @Tracking VALUES (6,  1, '2016-04-01');
INSERT INTO @Tracking VALUES (7,  1, '2016-05-01');
INSERT INTO @Tracking VALUES (8,  1, '2016-05-01');
INSERT INTO @Tracking VALUES (9,  1, '2016-06-01');
INSERT INTO @Tracking VALUES (19, 1, '2016-06-01');

INSERT INTO @Events VALUES (1, 1, '2016-02-01');
INSERT INTO @Events VALUES (2, 1, '2016-03-01');
INSERT INTO @Events VALUES (3, 1, '2016-04-01');
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Some product specific SQL there...)

Comment: @jarlh oops, forgot :) Hmm, also a drive-by downvote, not sure why...

Comment: I have taken out the date-truncation from the example - it's not pertinent to the problem and is just adding noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A fix for your query**

1. Since you used `CID` in the PIVOT clause (`COUNT(CID)`), it is **not** being used as one of the PIVOT aggregate columns and you can't select it.
2. Since you use intermediate aggregation then it should be SUM and not COUNT.
3. You have mismatched `PersonId` with `Id`

---

- I've replaced `COUNT(CID)` with `SUM(Recrods)` and added `CID` to the SELECT clause.
- I've replace `PersonId` with `Id`
- You might want to replace eh/et/ev with `coalesce (...,0)`

---

```
SELECT CID,DateMonth, pvt.[EH], pvt.[ET], pvt.[EV] 
FROM
(
    SELECT PersonId AS CID,  HistoryDate AS DateMonth, 'EH' AS RecordType, COUNT(id) Records FROM @History   GROUP BY PersonId,  HistoryDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PersonId AS CID,  TrackingDate AS DateMonth, 'ET' AS RecordType, COUNT(id) Records FROM @Tracking GROUP BY PersonId,  TrackingDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PersonId AS CID, EventDate  AS DateMonth, 'EV' AS RecordType, COUNT(id) Records FROM @Events      GROUP BY PersonId, EventDate
) as x
PIVOT( SUM(Records) FOR RecordType IN ( [EH], [ET], [EV] ) ) as pvt
```

**A cleaner solution**

1. There is no need for intermediate group by
2. There is no need for separate aliasing of the UNION ALL parts

---

```
select  cid,datemonth,h,t,v

from    (           select PersonId, historydate  ,'h' from @history  
        union all   select PersonId, trackingdate ,'t' from @tracking 
        union all   select PersonId, eventdate    ,'v' from @events   
        ) as t (cid,datemonth,recordtype) 
            pivot (count(recordtype) for recordtype in (h,t,v)) as p
```

---

```
+-----+-------------------------+----+----+----+
| cid | datemonth               | h  | t  | v  |
+-----+-------------------------+----+----+----+
| 1   | 2016-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 1  | 1  | 1  |
+-----+-------------------------+----+----+----+
| 1   | 2016-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 2  | 0  | 1  |
+-----+-------------------------+----+----+----+
| 1   | 2016-04-01 00:00:00.000 | 0  | 5  | 1  |
+-----+-------------------------+----+----+----+
| 1   | 2016-05-01 00:00:00.000 | 1  | 2  | 0  |
+-----+-------------------------+----+----+----+
| 1   | 2016-06-01 00:00:00.000 | 2  | 2  | 0  |
+-----+-------------------------+----+----+----+
| 1   | 2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 | 2  | 0  | 0  |
+-----+-------------------------+----+----+----+
| 1   | 2016-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 2  | 0  | 0  |
+-----+-------------------------+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Done. Please check.

Comment: Yes, as suspected I ended up down a misdirection of a rabbit hole. This works as intended, thanks. I actually worked it out too, at about the same time :)

Answer (score 0):

In postsgresql you can use

```
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', date_column)
```

Comment: Yeah I think I rushed it a bit. Should I just delete my answer?

Comment: It is MSSQL, but the rounding of date to the nearest month is not the tricky bit.

Comment: Yes, now that I read it again I realise my mistake. I suspect you can't do all 3 at the same time with a clean and fast query. I don't know mssql very well so I might be wrong.

Comment: @hvm2hvm Yeah, I'm hoping I've missed something. These are potentially enormous tables, so the cleaner it is the better.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can to do better but it works.

```
WITH eventss as (
SELECT COUNT(ID) as cnt, PERSONID, YEAR(eventdate) as y, MONTH(eventdate) as m
FROM @Events
GROUP BY PERSONID, YEAR(eventdate), MONTH(eventdate)
),
 tracking as (
SELECT COUNT(ID) as cnt, PERSONID, YEAR(trackingdate) as y, MONTH(trackingdate) as m
FROM @Tracking
GROUP BY PERSONID, YEAR(trackingdate), MONTH(trackingdate)
),
 history as (
SELECT COUNT(ID) as cnt, PERSONID, YEAR(historydate) as y, MONTH(historydate) as m
FROM @History
GROUP BY PERSONID, YEAR(historydate), MONTH(historydate)
),
ttime as (  SELECT YEAR(historydate) as y,MONTH(historydate) as m FROM @History UNION
            SELECT YEAR(trackingdate) as y,MONTH(trackingdate) as m FROM @Tracking UNION
            SELECT YEAR(eventdate) as y,MONTH(eventdate) as m FROM @Events 
)
SELECT c.id, DATEFROMPARTS(tt.y,tt.m,1) as date, ISNULL(h.cnt,0) as Hist, ISNULL(tr.cnt,0) as Trck, ISNULL(e.cnt,0) as Evt
FROM @Contacts AS c
CROSS JOIN ttime AS tt
LEFT JOIN eventss AS e ON c.Id=e.PERSONID AND tt.m=e.m AND tt.y=e.y
LEFT JOIN tracking AS tr ON c.Id=tr.PERSONID AND tt.m=tr.m AND tt.y=tr.y
LEFT JOIN history AS h ON c.Id=h.PERSONID AND tt.m=h.m AND tt.y=h.y
```